# How to flatten this List<C1> where C1 contains a collection of C2 of a single element using Stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a structure like this (simplified):

```
class C1 {
    Integer id;
    Set<C2> c2Set;
    public C1 add(C2 c2) {
        c2Set.add(c2);
        return this;
    }
    //equals and hashcode methods based on id field.
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "C1: {" + id + ", " + c2Set + "}";
    }
}
class C2 {
    Integer id;
    //equals and hashcode methods based on id field.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "C2: " + id;
    }
}
```

To fill this structure, I execute the following query:

```sql
SELECT c1.id, c2.id
FROM tablex c1
    INNER JOIN tablex_tabley d ON d.c1id = c1.id
    INNER JOIN tabley c2 ON c2.id = d.c2id
ORDER BY c1.id;
```

And this is directly read from a `ResultSet` (using JDBI) line by line. The structure of the data read looks similar to this:

```
List<C1> c1List = asList(
    new C1(1).add(new C2(1)),
    new C1(1).add(new C2(2)),
    new C1(2).add(new C2(1))
);
```

I need to flatten this list to make it look as if it was created like this:

```
List<C1> c1List = asList(
    new C1(1).add(new C2(1)).add(new C2(2)),
    new C1(2).add(new C2(1))
);
```

Currently I use this piece of code that does the job:

```
Map<C1, C1> c1Map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (C1 c1 : c1List) {
    if (!c1Map.containsKey(c1)) {
        c1Map.put(c1, c1);
    } else {
        C1 prevC1 = c1Map.get(c1);
        for (C2 c2 : c1.c2Set) {
            prevC1.add(c2);
        }
    }
}
List<C1> c1ListReduce = new ArrayList<>(c1Map.values());
//just to check the results
System.out.println(c1ListReduce);
```

How can I achieve the same using Java 8 streams? I cannot find a way to group all the C2's instances that belong to a C1 instance and return a `List<C1>` (or any other collection, probably a `Set<C1>`) where this are flattened without knowing the elements I already visited and retrieving them to add them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same spirit of Dmitry Ginzburg but implemented differently.

```
List<C1> list = c1List.stream()
                      .collect(toMap(c -> c.id, c -> c.c2Set, (set1, set2) -> Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream()).collect(toSet())))
                      .entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .map(e -> new C1(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                      .collect(toList());
```

It uses the `toMap()` collector. From the `List<C1>`, you create a `Map<Integer, Set<C2>>` that maps each C1's id to its set `c2Set`. If you have one similar id, you merge the two values (i.e the sets) in another new set.

Finally you get the entry set and map each entry to a new C1 instance and  you collect all the instances into a List.

(I assumed there is a constructor that accepts a Set as parameter)

Comment: The only part I don't understand is this: `(set1, set2) -> Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream())`. What does it mean?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This is the merge function used if you have two identical keys. This function takes two values as parameter (that corresponds to the value associated with the key) and return a value of the same type. Here each value is the set associated with a particular C1 instance. So `set1` corresponds to the `c2Set`  set of one C1 instance and set2 to the `c2Set` set of another C1 instance and this function merges the two sets in another set by concatenating their respective streams and collecting them in a new set.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So if the map contains already the mapping `1 -> Set[C2(1)]` and that you insert the mapping `1 -> Set[C2(2)]`, this merge function will be called to produce the mapping `1 -> Set[C2(1), C2(2)]`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like all you have to do is to group elements by common `id` and then union them inside one `C1`:

```
List<C1> newC1List = c1List.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(C1::getId/*getters should be implementer*/))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> /*constructor should be implemented*/
                new C1(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().stream().flatMap(c1 -> c1.getC2Set().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet())))
        .collect(toList());
```

Let's go step by step in explaining this code:

1. The first `collect` line is creating the new `Map`, which maps the `id` to the list of elements with this `id`.
2. In the next two lines we're creating `Stream` of pairs (`Map.Entry` actually), in which key is the `id`, and the value is the list of `C1`'s, which have this `id`.
3. The next operation is merging all the `C1`s from the value to one `C1` (`Map.Entry<Integer, List<C1>> -> C1`). The `id` is taken from the key of entry, though I can use the id of the first element from `List`, but it looks more ugly :)

   So, the `id` of element would be `entry.getKey()`, and `c2Set` is the merge of all the `Set`s inside `C1`s into one `Set`. This operation is easily done with `flatMap` operation of `Stream` (`concatMap` analogue from Haskell).
4. I convert this `Stream` to `List` with `collect` method.

Comment: Works as expected. Could you provide an explanation for readers on what's exactly going on in this code?